# How to prove logic equivalence in Coq?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I want to prove the following logic equivalence in Coq.

(p->q)->(~q->~p)

Here is what I attempted. How can I fix this?

```
Lemma work : (forall p q : Prop, (p->q)->(~q->~p)).
Proof.
intros p q.
intros p_implies_q not_q_implies_not_p.
refine (not_q_implies_not_p).
refine (p_implies_q).
Qed.
```

Comment: That theorem is not an equivalence, it is a conditional.

Comment: You know you can’t just hit refine if the type isn’t the same as the goal? Also the last intros will take up $\lnot q,$ not $(\lnot q\to \lnot p)$ so that’s a bad name for it. This much you could have seen stepping through, so your attempt strikes me as rather lazy.

Comment: Also, its best to just unpack and then work it out in terms of logic. Assuming $p\to q$ and $q\to\bot$ and $p,$ can you derive $\bot$?